# gcloud always uses default credentials

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcloud

I ran into trouble with gcloud credentials. It always uses default user credentials even when I add new credentials with `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=[PATH]`. When I list my credentials with `gcloud auth list`, I can see active credentials which I added earlier.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any troubles with gcloud on Linux (my OS)?

Answer (score 2):

When you list the accounts that are configured by using `gcloud auth list` you should see the service account added. If it is not set as active (with * ) then you can select it by using `gcloud config set account YOUR_SERV_ACC`. There are no problems with gcloud on Linux, you probably also need to [revoke](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/revoke)  previously generated [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/) : `gcloud auth application-default revoke`.